# Como puedo llamar a mi botón desde un ListView?

Tags: android, botón, listview, onclick, adapter

Estoy intentado seleccionar un botón insertado en un `ListView` y que a partir de ahí el botón tenga una acción al seleccionarlo.

**Este es mi código:**

Dónde debería llamar a mi método **onClick**??

```
class GetCorrectivos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> implements  View.OnClickListener {
    String status = null;
    Activity context;
    ListView lv;
```

Defino el botón:

```
    Button fechaAtendido = findViewById(R.id.fechaAtendido);

    public GetCorrectivos(Activity context, ListView lv) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lv = lv;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        **fechaAtendido.setOnClickListener(this)** Esto me da errorr
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... connUrl) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        BufferedReader reader;

        try {
            final URL url = new URL(connUrl[0]);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int result = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (result == 200) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    status = line;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return status;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {
            try {
                ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                   // las variables
                    BrandList.add(itemList);
                }

                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(EquipoCorrectivo.this, BrandList, R.layout.item_correctivo, new String[] { "ID_CORRECTIVO", "ID_OT_EQUIPO", "FECHA_CORRECTIVO", "ATENDIDO", "FECHA_ATENDIDO", "REALIZADO", "FECHA_REALIZADO",  "ZONA_PRODUCCION", "UBICACION", "DESCRIPCION", "SOLUCION"}, new int[]{R.id.idCorrectivo, R.id.idOTEq, R.id.fechaCorrectivo, R.id.atendido, R.id.fechaAtendido, R.id.realizado, R.id.fechaRealizado, R.id.zonaProd, R.id.ubica, R.id.descrip,  R.id.solu});

                ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) lv).setAdapter(adapter);
                // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // lv.invalidate();
                // lv.requestLayout();
                // lv.forceLayout();

                if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(EquipoCorrectivo.this, "vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(EquipoCorrectivo.this, "Por favor active la conexión VPN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

He intentado llamar aquí al método **onClick** pero no hay manera

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.fechaAtendido:
```

Aquí intento que el botón haga algo:
Toast.makeText(EquipoCorrectivo.this, "mprueba", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
}

Alguien me podría echar una mano?
No consigo que mi botón tenga una acción cuando lo selecciono

Comment: ¿El botón es para cada elemento de la lista?

Comment: esto no es java estándard, seguro que no es java para android?

Comment: @FranCámara Sí, El botón es para cada elemento

Comment: @RuslanLópez Sí, es para Android. Gracias por la observación.

Comment: @DanielSzekely siempre que tengas un problema en Android es importante revisar el LogCat, agrega el problema que se muestra ahí, revisa donde dice "Caused by" y agregalo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score -1):

Te sugiero, si no lo has hecho, que el ListView lo uses con un Adapter, donde puedas crear cada elemento de tu lista, hay muchísima documentación al respecto.

Aquí tienes un par de ejemplos para poder hacerlo con Activities y  Fragments:
https://programacionymas.com/blog/listas-dinamicas-android-usando-recycler-view-card-view

http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/recursos/34-unidad-3-actividades-e-intenciones/128-la-vista-listview

Particularmente te recomiendo usar Fragments, pero eso ya depende de las necesidades que tengas en tu proyecto.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.